# how to remove slideUp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove these Slide up function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#tabBar ul.buttons > li > a").on("click", function(e){
        //if submenu is hidden, does not have active class
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

            // hide any open menus and remove active classes
            $("#tabBar ul.buttons li ul").slideUp(350);
            $("#tabBar ul.buttons li a").removeClass("active");

            // open submenu and add the active class
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
            $(this).addClass("active");

        //if submenu is visible
        }else if($(this).hasClass("active")) {

            //hide submenu and remove active class
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
    });
});
```

**when i add another div to the body by Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Collapse_menu").click(function(){
        $(".bodyStatic").toggleClass("collapse-body");
        //comment: here i want to add my code so that when i call collapse-body the top slide up function should remove
    });
});
```

I am making a collapsable menu here are the images which helps you for better understanding

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to cover that `.slideUp()` in some kind of condition that fires on true and otherwise not.

Comment: How :( I am not so expert in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is my try

```
if($(".bodyStatic").hasClass("collapse-body"))
{
    //DO NOTHING
}
else
{
    $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
}

//OR VICE VERSA
```

Comment: what i have to write in place of do nothing... So that i can remove the slideup function

Comment: You can put everything except `.slideUp()` in there, if your condition satisfies of having class `.collapse-body`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding whenever you `click` on `.Collapse_menu`, you want to collapse the horizontally expanded menu as well as close the vertically opened submenu. If this is the case then you may want to try below code:

**Code1:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#tabBar ul.buttons > li > a").on("click", function(e){

        if($(".bodyStatic").hasClass("collapse-body"))
        {
            $(".bodyStatic").removeClass("collapse-body")
        }
        //if submenu is hidden, does not have active class
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

            // hide any open menus and remove active classes
            $("#tabBar ul.buttons li ul").slideUp(350);
            $("#tabBar ul.buttons li a").removeClass("active");

            // open submenu and add the active class
            $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
            $(this).addClass("active");

        //if submenu is visible
        }else if($(this).hasClass("active")) {

            //hide submenu and remove active class
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
        }
    });
});
```

**Code2:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Collapse_menu").click(function(){
        $(".bodyStatic").toggleClass("collapse-body");

        var activeSubmenu = $("#tabBar ul.buttons > li > a.active"); //grab the active submenu if any
        //hide submenu and remove active class
        $(activeSubmenu).removeClass("active");
        $(activeSubmenu).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    });
});
```

Please let me know the outcome.

Comment: No i just try your code but its not working... Its same case like before

Comment: can its possible for you to post HTML and CSS too. Or otherwise if possible please try to create jsfiddle of it.

Comment: OK wait i am uploading it to my server and send you link within 5 minutes

Comment: Here is the link you can download it if you wish.. In html page i added my JS to call 'collapse-body' and rest of the JS you can find in moidul.js
http://www.dwebworld.com/help/slide_up/index.htm

Comment: @moiduldargahi - could you please try replacing your 2 piece of codes with these 2 codes. I hope it will work as required.

Comment: Yes it works but see these image a small issue arise.
http://www.evernote.com/shard/s671/sh/65e8817c-9eb4-4c59-bdd0-a833b41d5635/5b26a10fea52f6942eb35576188a1dfc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98968/discussion-between-vijayp-and-moidul-dargahi).